# Prove that $\ln x \leq x - 1$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

I need help with this proof for my real analysis class. it is on the practice sheets and we do NOT get an answer. I proved $\ln(x) < x−1$ for all $x>1$ by contradiction but cannot do this one.

Prove that $\ln(x) \leq x−1$ for all $x>0$.

i believe you need to use MVT, I cannot use the famous inequality $e^x>x+1$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Please ue Latex in future for making your formulae more readable - in this case it would have been as simple as putting dollar signs around your formulae. You can click the edit button on any of your questions to see the code if you need more details.

Comment: will do! Thanks!

Comment: Both functions agree at $1$.  Compute their derivatives to show that log increases at a slower rate for $x \geq 1$ and increases at a faster rate for $x \leq 1$.  Use the mean value theorem to justify that this is enough to show the desired equality holds.

Comment: @JackM : To call it "LaTeX" is somewhat silly at best.  It's MathJax.  LaTeX has all sorts of typesetting abilities, not just mathematical notation.

Comment: Nice question! Can anyone suggest a good book for this kind of analysis-exercises? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Apply what you've already proven using $\ln(\frac{1}{x})=-\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

To prove: $lnx \leq x - 1$ for $x > 0$. Since you've done the part for $x > 1$, we show: the inequality true for $x \in (0, 1]$. At $x = 1$ we have equality, so consider $x \in (0, 1)$. Then $0 < 1 - x < 1$. So, using a power series expansion for $ln(1 - x)$ at $1 - x$ we have:
$\ln x = \ln(1 - (1-x)) = -(1-x) - \dfrac{(1-x)^2}{2} - \dfrac{(1-x)^3}{3} - \dfrac{(1-x)^4}{4} -\cdots-\dfrac{(1-x)^n}{n}-\cdots < -(1-x) = x - 1$

Answer (score 2):

If $x=1$ it's true. Suppose $0<x<1$. Define $f(x)=\ln x -x +1$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1$. As $0<x<1$, $f'(x)>0$, then $f$ is crescent. So $f(x)<f(1)$ for $0<x<1$.As $f(1)=0$, $\ln x -x +1<0$, therefore $\ln x ≤ x - 1$ for $0<x≤1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for $y>1$  $$\int_1^y\frac{dt}{t^2}\leqslant\int_1^y\frac{dt}t\leqslant\int_1^y dt$$  gives $$\tag 1 1-\frac 1 y \leqslant \log y \leqslant y-1$$

with equality iff $y=1$. If $0<y'<1$, write $y= \frac 1{ y'}$ and use the above to get $$1 - y'\leqslant \log \frac{1}{{y'}}\leqslant \frac{1}{{y'}} - 1$$ and multiply by $-1$ to get $(1)$ is true also in this case.