# Show that $4x + \log_2 x$ is $\Theta(x)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms

Show that $4x+\log_2 x$ is $\Theta$(x)
Unsure how to do this I think I've found $\Omega$(x).

Here's what I did:

$x\le4x + \log_2 x$. Let $A = 1$ and $a = 1$ $A|x| \le |4x + \log_2 x |$ x > a
Hence by $\Omega$ notation $4x + \log_2 x$ is $\Omega$(x).

Comment: Do you mean $\Theta$ instead of $\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof for $\Omega(x)$ is right. In order to complete it to $\Theta(x)$ consider the inequality $\ln(x)\leq x-1$ (see [Prove that $\ln x \leq x - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772102/prove-that-ln-x-leq-x-1))
Now $\log_2(x)=\ln(x)/\ln 2$, therefore for $x\geq 1$
$$0\leq |4x+\log_2 x|=4x+\log_2 x=4x+\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}\leq 4x+\frac{x-1}{\ln 2}\leq 
 \left(4+\frac{1}{\ln 2}\right)x\leq 6 x.$$

Comment: i don't quite understand how this helps

Comment: @Dreeww You would like to show that $|4x + \log_2 x| \leq c |x|$ for some constant $c$. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. i think i have finished the question.. by adding $3x + \log_2 x$ to both sides it should give $3x + \log_2 x \le 7x + log_2 x$ correct? where c = 7?

Comment: In this way you still have the logarithm on the right side. Consider $\log_2(x)=\ln(x)/\ln 2$

Comment: how did you get to 6?

Comment: You can leave $\left(4+\frac{1}{\ln 2}\right)$ as a constant $c$.It is about $5.4426$.