# Inequality $\ln(x)x^2+x^4-x^5<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to prove this inequality but am unable to do so. Derivatives and graphing not permitted. Any hint?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2\ln{x}+x^4-x^5<1$?

Comment: it seems that is $$x^2\ln(x)+x^4-x^5<0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Strict inequality does not hold at $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $x > 0$ so that $\ln(x)$ is defined (without complex numbers) and using the fact* that $\ln(x) \le x-1$,

\begin{eqnarray}
\ln(x) x^2 + x^4 - x^5 &\le& (x-1) x^2 + x^4(1-x)\\
 &=& (1-x)(x^2 - 1)x^2\\
\end{eqnarray}

For $0 < x < 1$, this product is negative. At $1$, it's $0$. Finally, for $x > 1$ it's negative again.

Thus $\ln(x) x^2 + x^4 - x^5 \le (1-x)(x^2-1)x^2 \le 0 < 1$ for all $x > 0$.

---

*This fact will have to be shown separately. E.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772102/prove-that-ln-x-leq-x-1).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^5-x^4+1}{x^2}-\ln{x}$.

Hence, $$f'(x)=3x^2-2x-\frac{2}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{3x^5-2x^4-x^2-2}{x^3},$$
which by Descartes has unique positive root $x_1$.

Thus, $x_1=x_{min}$ and $x_1=1.208...$ and since $f(x_1)>0$, we are done!

By the same way we can prove that $\ln{x}\leq x^3-x^2$