# How to prove $1+\frac{1}{2} \ln(x) \leq \sqrt{x}$ when $x \ge 1$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Please help proving that $1+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x) \leq \sqrt{x}$ when $x \ge 1$.

I tried with $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)=\ln{\sqrt{x}}$ then use $X=\sqrt{x}$. So we need to prove: $1+\ln{X} \leq X$ but then I'm stuck

Thank you so much.

Comment: This inequality goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: It is the other way around, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/772102/42969

Comment: Yes thank you all - this was the first time I used LaTex syntax - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE,you can take $$f(x)= 1+\frac12 \ln x -\sqrt x$$over $[1,+\infty)$now check $f'(x)$
$$f'=\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}=\\\frac12 (\frac{1}{\sqrt x})(\frac1{\sqrt x}-1)\\=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}(\frac{1-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x})\leq 0 $$ so $f(x) $ is decreasing function over $[1,+\infty)$   can you take over now ?

Comment: Yes thank you so much - so my initial idea to use $X=\sqrt{x}$ was wrong - or could it be use as well?

Answer (score 2):

Picking up where the OP left off, having reduced the inequality to showing that $1+\ln X\le X$ for $X\ge1$, note that

$$\ln X=\int_1^X{dt\over t}\le\int_1^Xdt=X-1$$

since $1/t\le1$ for $t\ge1$.

Answer (score 0):

First, we define the function $f(x)= \sqrt{x}-1-\frac{1}{2}\ln x$. Notice that
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{2x} = \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{2x}\geq 0,\phantom{a} \forall x\in[1,+\infty)$$

Now, notice that
$$f(1)=\sqrt{1}-1+\frac12\ln(1)=0,$$
so $f(1)\geq 0$ and $f$ is an increasing function in the interval $[1,+\infty)$, so from this it is concluded that
$$f(x)\geq 0, \forall x\in[1,+\infty),$$
hence that $\sqrt{x}\geq 1+\frac12\ln x$ for all $x\geq1$.